# Getting 'str' object has no attribute 'get' in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

views.py

```
def generate_xml(request, number):
    caller_id = 'x-x-x-x'
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()

    with resp.dial(callerId=caller_id) as r:
         if number and re.search('[\d\(\)\- \+]+$', number):
            r.number(number)
         else:
             r.client('test')
   return str(resp)
```

url.py

```
url(r'^voice/(?P<number>\w+)$', 'django_calling.views.generate_xml', name='generating TwiML'),
```

Whenever I am requesting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/voice/number?id=98` getting following error:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/voice/number?id=90
Django Version:     1.6.2
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
```

Full Traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/voice/number?id=90

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
 ('django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_calling',
'django_twilio',
'twilio')
 Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
```

I have just started to learn `Django`.

Comment: Are you sure, this view is getting called? Put a pdb inside this view to make sure the view gets called.

Comment: Post full traceback, please.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can not pass directly `str` as a `django response` .
You must use

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

if you want to render string data as django view response.
have a look [django.http.HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse)

```
return HttpResponse(resp)
```

Comment: It works but it is printing r.clinet('test') not r.number(number)? Any idea? If i directly return any integer it is giving the same error

Comment: there may be  a change that it is always going into else statement . i will suggest you to cross check your re and your logic again to get mobile or client number .

Comment: It is `return HttpResponse(resp)` instead of `return Httpresponse(resp)`.

Answer (score 6):

Django views must always return an `HttpResponse` object, so try wrapping that string in an HttpResponse:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse(str(resp))
```

Additionally, the `number` variable in `generate_xml` will contain only the string `'number'`, not the GET parameter. To get that, you might use:

```
request.GET.get('id')
```

Comment: It works but it is printing `r.clinet('test')` not `r.number(number)`? Any idea? If i directly return any integer it is giving the same error

Comment: Are you certain your regular expression is correct? Remember, anything you return must be wrapped in an HttpResponse, so if you want to return an integer, it must be return HttpResponse(str(the_number)).

Comment: @PrashantGaur Actually logic is simple here. I am just requesting to a url which is calling a method written in views.py

Comment: What if, I have to print the value of `number` here. I am using `pdb.settrace()` but it is printing `number` as a string

Comment: can you by converting  number = int(number) only for testing purposse

Comment: What is the output of `print repr(number), re.search('[\d\(\)\- \+]+$', number)` after the `with` line?

Comment: @PrashantGaur :  

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'number'

Comment: i am sure you are sending wrong data do
 your url .  please check value of  print number ... you can easily get what wrong you are doing

Comment: @PrashantGaur this is the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/voice/number?id=2083522792`, How to check it with `pdb`?

Comment: Aha! I am so sorry . You are correct 
I checked with pdb and it is just giving a string `number`, This is the stacktrace:
`Pdb) request
<WSGIRequest
path:/voice/number,
GET:<QueryDict: {u'id': [u'2083522792']}>,
`

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Updated my answer.