# sending mails with different domain names in python

Tags: django, python-2.7, sendmail

I'm getting "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server" while sending mails with different domain names.
For example, I have sent mails using person@example.com. Here my domain is example.com.

when I trying send mail I am getting "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server" error

### here is my code

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.somedomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'Admin@somedomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '***********'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**views.py**

```
msg = "Hi,this is testing mail."
try:
    send_mail('Appointment mail',msg,'',['user@somedomain.com'])
    response = 'Message sent successfully.You will receive response in very soon.Thank you.' 
except Exception as e:
    response = e
return HttpResponse(response)
```

Can anyone help me, Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I'm getting problems" isn't a helpful description. Post the error message or describe exactly what and when its failing.

Comment: I have added my traceback, please check and I am getting this error when reach "send_mail()" . I am added a print statement in exception block, but that print statement also not executed, I think exception block not raised. Thanks

Comment: I have getting authentication error because of the account I provided in the settings.py is don't have the access for less secure apps. That's why I getting authentication error.I have given the access for less secure app in my account then working fine.

Comment: Thanks for who respond to my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could help you. [Getting 'str' object has no attribute 'get' in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788135/getting-str-object-has-no-attribute-get-in-django). You cannot return 'str' directly as a response. You need HttpResponse

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse(response)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, now I didn't get that error but I'm  getting another error.

Comment: Why I am getting "SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server" error. any suggestions.

Comment: Can you put the stacktrace?

Comment: If you don't mind, let me know is it possible to send mails using smtp server with different domain names for example: san@example.com, san@bluetree.com etc.

Comment: I think you can. But you need to configure the SMTP server. I think this could help you. https://www.christiaan.com/thoughts/django-email-form-and-smtp-settings-tutorial/